# jquery ajax get XML from another domain

Tags: ajax, jquery, get, vimeo

Hey all here is my code i have to read an XML file from a Vimeo website:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/51229736.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('video').each(function(){
            var thumbURL = $(this).attr('thumbnail_small');
            alert(thumbURL);
            $('#vidThumb').html('<img src="' + thumbURL + '">');
        });
    },
    error: function(err) {alert('err');}
  });
});
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<videos>
  <script/>
    <video>
       <id>51229736</id>
       <title>CHATT HISTORY CENTER FILMS CAVALIER</title>
       <description/>
       <url>http://vimeo.com/51229736</url>
       <upload_date>2012-10-11 13:08:51</upload_date>
<thumbnail_small>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/353/072/353072229_100.jpg</thumbnail_small>
<thumbnail_medium>http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/353/072/353072229_200.jpg</thumbnail_medium>
......
</video>
</videos>
```

Problem being is that it errors out. I'm sure its because of the different domain name trying to read it so how can i fix that in order to do that?

Comment: is there any possibilty of requesting jsonp response from this site instead of XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieved it by doing the following:

```
 var vimeoVideoID = '51229736';
    $.getJSON('http://www.vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + vimeoVideoID + '.json?callback=?', {format: "json"}, function(json) {
    $("#vidThumb").attr('src', json[0].thumbnail_small);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is in setting the callback to "?" at least it usually is for me. This at least works with JSON. And if it were JSON, this is how I would do it:

```
var query = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/51229736.xml&callback=?';
$.ajax({
    url: query,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(s) { 
       console.log('success' + s)
    },
    error: function(e) { console.log('something went wrong!', e)}
});
```

Comment: Yeah, It's only available for JSONP... I will change my code to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that through jQuery's ajax across different domains using XML   , you can use `callback=?`  to get jsonp response back like in the other answer , if it is possible to get json response from that url

You should have no problem getting an XML response from your server side , you should probably try that route